# UI / UX for matching records

Tags: user-interface, user-input, user-experience

I know that this is a forum for programmers (not designers) but UX decisions are often left to us. So I am asking you guys/gals:

Has anyone come across a good paradigm for presenting two lists of information to the user for the user to match up?

I am not looking for a control or pre-built solution per se (though examples would be great) or even a real concrete design. I am just looking for ideas of how to present it to the users.

We are talking about two very long lists (thousands of records) where there is a one to one relationship between some (but not all) records in the two lists, and the user needs to match them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to post exactly the same question. In my case I need to match circa 1500 textual records (but not 1:1).
What I am currently thinking about is to show to lists sorted in such a way that already matched elements can be connected by straight lines without crossing. Above both lists I will put textbox which will allow to filter the list according to entered keywords.
To match elements the user will perform a gesture similar to drag&drop or drawing an arrow.
To remove a matching user will click an arrow.

Comment: Yup. That's pretty much what I did

Answer (score -1):

UX designers can use usability testing and UX research methodologies to help prevent misaligned mental models. Designers can also focus on interactive tours, careful onboarding, and real-time feedback to improve misaligned mental models.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).